# Forma de Onda desde un archivo .json con Python

Tags: python, json

Tengo unos valores (y) de amplitudes de una señal de vibraciones y para el eje (x) temporal sólo me dice que hay datos cada 0.000039, es un delta(x).

He logrado hacer la gráfica con amplitudes (y) Vs. Nº de muestras (x) que son unos 256000 n.

No sé como realizar desde dentro del código una asignación del delta(x) para los valores (y) de amplitud y después, realizar la gráfica forma de onda.

Si alguien me puede echar un cable, estaré muy agradecido.

Gracias!!!

Comment: Hola Cristian, bienvenido, para poder ayudarte, necesitamos tu código, edita tu pregunta y agregalo en formato texto, y sería de mucha ayuda, que nos mostrarás una parte de la entrada y el grafico esperado para ella. 
Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: cómo hiciste el gráfico? podés crear un vector x usando numpy: `import numpy as np` y en otra linea `x = np.arange(0,n*dx,dx)` esto lo que hace es crear un vector de largo n que vaya como `[0,dx,2dx,3dx,...,n*dx]`

Comment: Hola. Logré realizar la forma de onda como me comentabas Ulises Bussi en el comentario anterior pero ahora tengo problemas para representar la FFT correspondiente a esa forma de onda. He utilizado el paquete from scipy.fftpack import fft... pero no soy capaz de sacar la fft correspondiente a la forma de onda.